# CharInSet Compiler Warning in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I have following statement in my Delphi 7 code.

```
TMyCharSet = set of char;
```

When I migrated that code to Delphi XE4, I am getting following compiler warning at above line.

```
W1050 WideChar reduced to byte char in set expressions.  Consider using 'CharInSet' function in 'SysUtils' unit.
```

How should I redeclare TMyCharSet?

Comment: You could change to AnsiChar. A Set is limited to 256 elements. Consider e.g. how `Const
y : TMyCharSet=(['a','ش']);
` should be interpreted

Comment: Have you read Marco's white paper and the official documentation? Don't attempt Unicode migration without doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the warning because XE4 uses WideChar for variable of Char type (and WideString for String), so Char takes 2 bytes instead of 1 byte now. Now it is possible to keep unicode characters in String/Char, but for same reason it is impossible to use set of char anymore (in Delphi it is fixed size, 32-bytes bits map and can keep up to 256 items so).

If you use only chars from range #0..#127 (only latin/regular symbols), then you can just replace Char -> AnsiChar (but when you will assign it from Char you will see another warning, you will have to use explicit type conversion to suppress it).

If you need national/unicode symbols, then there is no "ready to use" structure in Delphi, but you can use Tdictionary for this purpose:

```
type
  TEmptyRecord = record end;

  TSet<T> = class(TDictionary<T,TEmptyRecord>)
  public
    procedure Add(Value: T); reintroduce; inline;
    procedure AddOrSetValue(Value: T); reintroduce; inline;
    function Contains(Value: T):Boolean; reintroduce; inline;
  end;

procedure TSet<T>.Add(Value: T);
var Dummy: TEmptyRecord;
begin
  inherited AddOrSetValue(Value, Dummy);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.AddOrSetValue(Value: T);
var Dummy: TEmptyRecord;
begin
  inherited AddOrSetValue(Value, Dummy);
end;

function TSet<T>.Contains(Value: T): Boolean;
begin
  result := inherited ContainsKey(Value);
end;
```

Of course you will have initialize at as any other regular class.
But it will be still quite efficient (not so fast as "set of" of course, just because "set" is always limited by 256 items max size but highly optimized).

Alternatively you can create your own set class for unicode chars as map of bits, it will take 8kb of memory to keep all the bits and will be almost as fast as "set of".

Comment: Your type would be improved if it used aggregation rather than inheritance.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you explained, right at the start, why that code does not compile when Char maps to WideChar. The information is there in the answer, but tucked away.

Comment: @David I put small note about reasons of the warning, but i don't understand why aggregation can be better then inheritance in this case. Just to hide methods/functions which are not reintroduced (i think they can be usefull in some tasks indeed) ?  Could you explain please ?

Comment: Inheritance signifies "is a". But your set is not a dictionary. It is just implemented using one. Your type inherits all the members of the dictionary type. I don't think you want that.

Comment: @david It can be used without overriding at all, i just made frequently used methods more friendly. But in some situations it is usefull to have other inherited methods available too. So we have full power of original structure + friendly interface for most used functions.

Comment: But then you've got a dictionary rather than a set. And that's bad design. Inheritance is the quick way to do it, but you end up with a poor type in this case.

Comment: @David No, i get a set. Any dictionary is set of pairs <key,value>, so Tdictionary can be used directly, i just made most common functions more friendly. You are lucky if you have time to make any code to be perfect, i don't :)

Comment: You don't have time not to do it right. Do it wrong and you'll save time now, but expend more time in the long run. Technical debt. You also don't need a lot of time to do it right. You can use existing collections. For example Delphi Spring: https://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/source/browse/trunk/Source/Base/Collections/Spring.Collections.Sets.pas

Comment: @David: The world is not black-white colored. There is no universal recipe for all situations. In this particular case aggregation doesn't provide any advantage (and code will be even slower a bit). And i have no any ideas why i should spend any additional time in future because of such design (except very general/academical considerations which are not related with this particular case from quite real life).

Comment: The world is not black and white. You are correct. I have one view. You have a different view.

Answer (score 7):

A set cannot contain items larger than a byte. Since `Char` in UniCode Delphi is a `WideChar` which is two bytes in size, a set type is an inappropriate container.

Here is an example of a generic set type based on a record, `TSet<T>`. This means that you don't have to think about creation and destruction of variables of this type. Use this type as a container for simple types. I tried to mimic most of the behavior of the set type.
Addition and subtraction of items can be done with + and - operators. Added the `in` operator as well.

Note: The record holds the data in a dynamic array. Assigning a variable to another will make both variables using the same dynamic array. A Copy-On-Write (COW) protection built-in will prevent a change in one variable to be reflected on the other one.

```
unit GenericSet;

interface

Uses
  System.Generics.Defaults;

Type
  TSet<T> = record
    class operator Add(const aSet: TSet<T>; aValue: T) : TSet<T>; overload;
    class operator Add(const aSet: TSet<T>; const aSetOfT: TArray<T>) : TSet<T>; overload;
    class operator Add(const aSet1: TSet<T>; const aSet2: TSet<T>) : TSet<T>; overload;
    class operator Subtract(const aSet: TSet<T>; aValue: T): TSet<T>; overload;
    class operator Subtract(const aSet: TSet<T>; const aSetOfT: TArray<T>) : TSet<T>; overload;
    class operator Subtract(const aSet1: TSet<T>; const aSet2: TSet<T>) : TSet<T>; overload;
    class operator In(aValue: T; const aSet: TSet<T>): Boolean; overload;
    class operator In(const aSetOf: TArray<T>; const aSet: TSet<T>): Boolean; overload;
    class operator In(const aSet1: TSet<T>; const aSet2: TSet<T>): Boolean; overload;
  private
    FSetArray : TArray<T>;
    function GetEmpty: Boolean;
  public
    procedure Add(aValue: T);
    procedure AddSet(const setOfT: array of T); overload;
    procedure AddSet(const aSet: TSet<T>); overload;
    procedure Remove(aValue: T);
    procedure RemoveSet(const setOfT: array of T); overload;
    procedure RemoveSet(const aSet : TSet<T>); overload;
    function Contains(aValue: T): Boolean; overload;
    function Contains(const aSetOfT: array of T): Boolean; overload;
    function Contains(const aSet : TSet<T>): Boolean; overload;
    procedure Clear;
    property Empty: Boolean read GetEmpty;
  end;

implementation

procedure TSet<T>.Add(aValue: T);
begin
  if not Contains(aValue) then begin
    SetLength(FSetArray,Length(FSetArray)+1);
    FSetArray[Length(FSetArray)-1] := aValue;
  end;
end;

class operator TSet<T>.Add(const aSet: TSet<T>; aValue: T): TSet<T>;
begin
  Result.AddSet(aSet.FSetArray);
  Result.Add(aValue);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.Add(const aSet: TSet<T>; const aSetOfT: TArray<T>): TSet<T>;
begin
  Result.AddSet(aSet.FSetArray);
  Result.AddSet(aSetOfT);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.Add(const aSet1, aSet2: TSet<T>): TSet<T>;
begin
  Result.AddSet(aSet1.FSetArray);
  Result.AddSet(aSet2.FSetArray);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.AddSet(const setOfT: array of T);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(setOfT) do
    Self.Add(setOfT[i]);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.AddSet(const aSet: TSet<T>);
begin
  AddSet(aSet.FSetArray);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.RemoveSet(const setOfT: array of T);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(setOfT) do
    Self.Remove(setOfT[i]);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.RemoveSet(const aSet: TSet<T>);
begin
  RemoveSet(aSet.FSetArray);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.Subtract(const aSet1, aSet2: TSet<T>): TSet<T>;
begin
  Result.AddSet(aSet1.FSetArray);
  Result.RemoveSet(aSet2.FSetArray);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.Subtract(const aSet: TSet<T>;
  const aSetOfT: TArray<T>): TSet<T>;
begin
  Result.AddSet(aSet.FSetArray);
  Result.RemoveSet(aSetOfT);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.Subtract(const aSet: TSet<T>; aValue: T): TSet<T>;
begin
  Result.AddSet(aSet.FSetArray);
  Result.RemoveSet(aValue);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.In(aValue: T; const aSet: TSet<T>): Boolean;
begin
  Result := aSet.Contains(aValue);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.In(const aSetOf: TArray<T>; const aSet: TSet<T>): Boolean;
begin
  Result := aSet.Contains(aSetOf);
end;

class operator TSet<T>.In(const aSet1: TSet<T>; const aSet2: TSet<T>): Boolean;
begin
  Result := aSet2.Contains(aSet1.FSetArray);
end;

function TSet<T>.Contains(aValue: T): Boolean;
var
  i : Integer;
  c : IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  c := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  Result := false;
  for i := 0 to Length(FSetArray)-1 do
    if c.Equals(FSetArray[i],aValue) then
      Exit(True);
end;

function TSet<T>.GetEmpty: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Length(FSetArray) = 0);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.Clear;
begin
  SetLength(FSetArray,0);
end;

function TSet<T>.Contains(const aSetOfT: array of T): Boolean;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := High(aSetOfT) >= 0;
  for i := 0 to High(aSetOfT) do
  begin
    Result := Contains(ASetOfT[i]);
    if not Result then
      Exit(false);
  end;
end;

function TSet<T>.Contains(const aSet: TSet<T>): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Contains(aSet.FSetArray);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.Remove(aValue: T);
var
  i : Integer;
  c : IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  c := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  for i := 0 to Length(FSetArray)-1 do
  begin
    if c.Equals(FSetArray[i],aValue) then
    begin
      SetLength(FSetArray,Length(FSetArray)); // Ensure unique dyn array
      if (i < Length(FSetArray)-1) then
        FSetArray[i] := FSetArray[Length(FSetArray)-1]; // Move last element
      SetLength(FSetArray,Length(FSetArray)-1);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

---

A sample test program:

```
program ProjectGenericSet;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    
uses
  GenericSet in 'GenericSet.pas';

var
 mySet,mySet1 : TSet<Char>;
begin
  mySet.AddSet(['A','B','C']);
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('C'));
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('D'));  // False
  mySet := mySet + 'D';
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('D'));
  WriteLn('D' in mySet);
  mySet := mySet - 'D';
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('D'));  // False
  mySet := mySet + TArray<Char>.Create('D','E');
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('D'));
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains(['A','D']));
  mySet1 := mySet;
  // Testing COW
  mySet1.Remove('A');
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('A'));
  mySet1:= mySet1 + mySet;
  WriteLn(mySet1.Contains('A'));
  mySet := mySet1;
  mySet1.Clear;
  WriteLn(mySet.Contains('A'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: This looks like a value type, but behaves like a reference type. Some of the time. Assign one variable to another and they both have a reference to the same dynamic array `FSetArray`. Until a call is made to `SetLength`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, ahh. Right, removing answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, added COW protection to avoid reference collisions. Hope I got it right this time!

Comment: +1 That's nice. My original comment wasn't intended to dismiss this answer out of hand. It was just a comment. Anyway, COW does the job.

Answer (score -1):

See fourm suggestions from web:

```
if not (CharInSet(Key,['0'..'9',#8]) then key := #0;
```

From: http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=66035&sid=f5838cc7dc991f7b3340e4e2689b222a