# Delphi XE2: How to use sets of integers with ordinal values > 255

Tags: delphi, set, limit, ordinal

All I want to do is to define a set of integers that may have values above 255, but I'm not seeing any good options.  For instance:

`with MyObject do Visible := Tag in [100, 155, 200..225, 240];   // Works just fine`

but

`with MyObject do Visible := Tag in [100, 201..212, 314, 820, 7006];   // Compiler error`

I've gotten by with (often lengthy) conditional statements such as:

`with MyObject do Visible := (Tag in [100, 202..212]) or (Tag = 314) or (Tag = 820) or (Tag = 7006);`

but that seems ridiculous, and this is just a hard-coded example.  What if I want to write a procedure and pass a set of integers whose values may be above 255?  There HAS to be a better, more concise way of doing this.

Comment: Or use a generic list, e.g.TList<T> as TList<integer>

Comment: Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d, it has a generic set solution for exactly this.

Comment: You can find a generic set implemented here: [Finding common elements in two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524788/576719)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The base type of a [Delphi set](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) must be an ordinal type with *at most* 256 distinct values. [Under the hood](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Set_Types), such a variable has one bit for each possible value, so a variable of type `set of Byte` has size 256 bits = 32 bytes.

Suppose it were possible to create a variable of type `set of Integer`. There would be 2<sup>32</sup> = 4294967296 distinct integer values, so this variable must have 4294967296 bits. Hence, it would be of size 512 MB. That's a HUGE variable. Maybe you can put such a value on the stack in 100 years.

Consequently, if you truly need to work with (mathematical) sets of integers, you need a custom data structure; the built-in `set` types won't do. For instance, you could implement it as an advanced record. Then you can even overload the [`in` operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)) to make it look like a true Pascal set!

Implementing such a slow and inefficient type is trivial, and that might be good enough for small sets. Implementing a general-purpose integer set data structure with efficient operations (membership test, subset tests, intersection, union, etc.) is more work. There might be third-party code available on the WWW (but StackOverflow is not the place for library recommendations).

If your needs are more modest, you can use a simple array of integers instead (`TArray<Integer>`). Maybe you don't need O(1) membership tests, subset tests, intersections, and unions?

Comment: I kind of figured that the only reason for the 256-value limitation would be if they were using bits as flags.  Very fast & efficient, but limited.  I just hoped that Delphi had a way to use set operations on arbitrary data sets.  Under the hood it would likely use lists, which is obviously far slower than doing an XOR on a DWord, but it would be nice to have that kind of flexibility available.  Okay, I can certainly do this any opf several ways, but I just wanted to see if I was overlooking a built-in function that I didn't know about.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -4):

I would say, that such task already requires a database. Something small and simple like TFDMemTable + TFDLocalSQL should do.

Comment: You think that adding the overhead of a database is appropriate for testing whether a control should be visible or not by seeing if its Tag value is in a list of integers?

Comment: @KenWhite Just look at these Tag values. I do not know, how author assigns them, but it looks like there is a lot of data there. And whenever you have a lot of data, it is always better to handle it with proper DB engine.

Comment: Nonsense. The highest tag number shown is 7006, and even if it were 700006, it's still a list of single integer values that are easily able to be stored in memory. A database for this simple task is far more inefficient.