# E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds when using more then 2 constants

Tags: delphi

```
procedure test();
const
  one = 100;
  two = 200;
  three = 300;
var
  arr: TArray<smallint>;
begin
  SetLength(arr, 1);
  arr[0] := 100;
  if arr[0] in [one, two] then Exit();
  if arr[0] in [one, two, three] then Exit();
end;
```

Weirdly enough, the error appears on the second condition and not the first. I suppose there's a compiler optimization to explain that, but I'd still like to be able to do this comparison using the `in` operator. Is there any way of satisfying the compiler here ?

Comment: The problem is not the number of elements in the set, but their magnitude. `three` is greater than 255. That's the problem. Google `Delphi set of Integer` for details.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016949/delphi-xe2-how-to-use-sets-of-integers-with-ordinal-values-255

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware doing [one, two] created a set instead of an array. Is there a way around this or do I have to use an actual, declared array for this ?

Comment: `in` can only be used with sets, not arrays. (But using operator overloading, you can define `in` operators for your own record types.) In your case, you could create a trivial function `IntegerInArray(AValue: Integer; const AArray: array of Integer): Boolean` using a `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna make a generic version that. How can I close this question ?

Comment: I think you should see a `Delete` link somewhere below it.